# Algorithm to allow two programs to update the same data

Tags: algorithm, communication, semaphore

This question is a long shot.  I don't think this is actually possible, but I thought I would post it just to see.

**Background:**

I have two systems.

1. One is a huge mainframe system that is more-or-less unchangeable.
2. The other is a WCF/SQL Server 2008 system I am writing.

The ONLY way the systems communicate is by sending XML data over NServiceBus and TCP.  The XML is then parsed by each system and acted on.  There is a possibility of several minutes in communication lag time.

The mainframe system is the actual "Owner" of all the data and users can connect directly to the mainframe at any time and make changes.  (There is no way to block them from making updates.)

**Question:**

I need to be able to send an update from my system, and be sure I am not overwriting a change that happened on the mainframe system.  Is there a way to do that?

**Example:**

I send an update for an order quantity to the main frame (to change it from 2 to 4).  But unknown to me, a user directly connected to the mainframe has updated the order quantity from 2 to 7.

When my update of 4 gets processed it will overwrite the update to 7.

If I had not sent the update to 4, eventually the mainframe would have told me about the update to 7.  But by the time it tells me, there could be another update by a mainframe user.

Comment: What if you get the data that you're updating each time that you're going to update and compare it against the new data? This way it will tell you if there's been another update since you last checked it.

Comment: Some clarification: 1) Are updates for the form "change quantity to X" or "increase quantity by X"?  2) Can user's updates be delayed, so long as they are not rejected?

Comment: @EricFrick - I cannot query from one system to the other.  The only communication is event message based.  And even if I could, there would be no way to know that an update would not occur in-between when I query and send my message and when the other system processes it.

Comment: @ScottHunter - they are "change quantity to X" changes (ie we overwrite).  It is fine to delay updates as long as they not rejected.

Comment: Other than no User ever having posted an update, under what circumstances should an update from your system not be rejected?  Put another way, once a User has posted an update, at what point would it be OK for your system's update be allowed to overwrite it?

Comment: @ScottHunter - I would have to have someone approve the confict and select "Overwrite"

Comment: @Vaccano - Good luck automating that :)

Comment: @ScottHunter - Yeah, it is not looking good for this feature.  I am thinking I may try a TimeStamp comparison to see if a conflict occurred and then have a manual process to resolve the conflict... But I am not sure that will even work.

Comment: @Vaccano I would not recommend a manual process never ever, because it makes you a system slave lol

Answer (score 4):

One way might be to send with every update both the original values and the new values of every relevant field. This would enable the receiving system to *detect* conflicts by comparing the original values with what it currently has in the database. How you resolve -- or flag -- those conflicts depends on your domain.

Another possibility might be to have a "version" column in every relevant table. The version number would get incremented on every update. Sending the version number alongside every update message could then be used as a means of detecting concurrent updates. On its own it will not help you to automatically resolve conflicts, however.

Comment: Both of these are really good ideas.  However, the message protocol between the systems is constrained to HL7.  The version of HL7 that we support does not allow for think kind of versioning or duplication.